# Using the PIVOT clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help creating a table using the pivot clause to include the average salary of each Division_ID and use Division_ID as a Row and Job_ID as Column using data in employees2 table.

Here is my query

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
  SELECT JOB_ID, DIVISION_ID, SALARY
  FROM employees2
  WHERE DIVISION_ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  )
PIVOT ( 
AVG(SALARY) FOR JOB_ID IN (1 AS ENG, 2 AS MGR, 3 AS PRE, 4 AS WOR, 5 AS TEC)
)
ORDER BY DIVISION _ID;
```

I get the following error when I try to execute the statement

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 3
```

Here is the data that is in employees2 table (note their are only 5 JOB_IDs)

[image: employees2 table]

Finally, here is an example of how my result should look like

[image: example result]

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server but it looks like you're using Oracle. Can you clarify and/or re-tag, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample data, your query is checking for `int` division_ids and job_ids, when it appears those are `varchar` fields.

Here is a working version:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
  SELECT JOB_ID, DIVISION_ID, SALARY
  FROM employees2
  WHERE DIVISION_ID IN ('div1','div2')
  ) 
PIVOT ( 
  AVG(SALARY) FOR JOB_ID IN ('job1', 'job2')
) 
ORDER BY 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f20ae/1)